# ST-Link high speed interface to access data stream from PC

Tags: stm32

I'm receiving 32bit samples from an external ADC via SPI (DMA) on the STM32U5 (NUCLEO board with ST-Link v3-E) at a rate of 51200 samples/sec. I'm trying to use STM32CubeMonitor to access these samples. I want to do this so I can analyze the stream and validate data acquisition using my PC.

I'm only able to achieve a sample rate of about 18600 samples/sec or 595kbps. I've had better (but insufficient) performance over the ST-Link v3-E's UART interface.

The ST-Link v3-E probe is configured in CubeMon for 24MHz frequency (I believe this uses the SWD interface?), so I expected higher throughput.

Should I be able to achieve higher bandwidth and I'm doing something wrong or is this really the expected limit? If the latter, is there another interface on the ST-Link v3-E that should get closer to USB FS (12Mbps) speeds?

Comment: I think you should be able to achieve this datarates over UART. At least according to: https://www.st.com/resource/en/technical_note/tn1235-overview-of-stlink-derivatives-stmicroelectronics.pdf I am not sure why you couldnt do it.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure why but above about 1.5Mbaud the error rate starts to increase dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly using STM32CubeMonitor and previous Studio variant, there is a rate limit of 1 kHz for single data requests, so you may try to read buffers of data every millisecond.

Looks like Segger J-Link supports speeds just over 240 kB/s for programming over swd, but I don't think you'll be able to access these speeds via their API.

The only option for these datarates (200 kB/s) I can think of is via the 20-pin trace output of the ARM debug core if you want to keep using standard parts, but I don't think you can use STM32CubeMonitor for that.